# Problems Boolean Modifier Blender 2.8

Tags: modifiers

I have some problems with booleam modifier. I have a cube and a mesh (two cylinders unified) and I want to apply a difference. The result I hope is to maintain the cube but with a hole with the cylinders shape but it doesn't work. I wish you could help me!. Thank you!!

**Before apply the modifier**

[image]

**After apply the modifier**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Booleans don't always work perfectly based on the geometry they are told to "cut" into. I hope there's not a specific reason you need the cylinder to be exactly there, because moving it a VERY small amount on the y axis before applying made it work for me. See below:

[image: BoolWorking]